# Handle acme-challenge Letsencrypt requests

Tags: node.js, apache, lets-encrypt

I have a **NodeJs app** running **behind an Apache configuration** using **ProxyPass**. The HTTPS is setup using **Letsencrypt**.

As you probably know, to validate a Letsencrypt certificat, we have to handle a request like the one bellow, sent by Letsencrypt server.

> http://sub.afakedomain.com/.well-known/acme-challenge/some-random-stringhere

At the moment, the request results into a **404 Not Found** because the ProxyPass redirect the request directly to my NodeJs app which didn't handle this request.

- A solution would be to define a route in my NodeJs app to handle the request
- Another solution would be to detect the request in Apache and instead of routing the request to the NodeJs app, route it directly to the folder containing the `.well-known` directory.

I would like to use **the Apache solution**, but I'm not able to find the right way to do it.

**Path to well-known directory**

`/var/www/html/.well-known/`

**My vhost setting**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
             DocumentRoot /var/www/html/fail
             ServerName sub.afakedomain.com
             RewriteEngine on
             RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^443$
             RewriteRule ^/(.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [L,R]
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
             ProxyPreserveHost On
             ProxyRequests Off
             ServerName sub.afakedomain.com
             Proxypass / http://localhost:5555/
             ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:5555/

             SSLEngine On
             SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/afakedomain.com/cert.pem
             SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/afakedomain.com/privkey.pem
             SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/afakedomain.com/chain.pem
             SSLCACertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/afakedomain.com/fullchain.pem
             Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
</VirtualHost>
```

If you have some suggestions, feel free! Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

If you want to exclude the `.well-known` directory from being proxied, you just need to add an exclusion. Add the following before the existing `ProxyPass` lines:

```
ProxyPass /.well-known/ !
```

And you should be all set. See the [ProxyPass](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxypass) documentation for more info.